# Locating IP on network

Tags: java, android

I have searched the web for this with no success.
This is my problem: I am developing an app that reads data from arduino connected with Ethernet shield.
I can connect to it on the internal network (home network) or through the Internet.

The problem is I need to know if the arduino is present on the local network and if not then look for it on the external ip address.
I have tried to use the ping function but it’s not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: define "used ping function" (what code did you use) and define "it's not working" (what did you expect, why did you expect that, what did happen, can you explain that)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know the IP address of the arduino?, have you tried putting your pc\laptop onto the same subnet as the device, e.g. if the arduino has an IP address of 10.254.103.20 you could change the IP of your laptop\pc to 10.254.103.21 and then try pinging it?

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing, if your router supports NAT loopback (most do, but you may have to enable it) you can always just connect to the external IP address, regardless of whether you're on LAN or WAN.

Cheers,